# How to restart nginx?

Tags: nginx, redhat

For me, I run "killall nginx" and start it by "sbin/nginx", anyone has a better restart script?

BTW: I install nginx from source, i do not find 'service nginx' command or /etc/init.d/nginx

Comment: Why are you installing from source?  Nginx packages are available for most good Server linux distributions.  Or you could roll your own packages, but not using packages is a bugger for maintainability.

Comment: because of mod_rails

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The nginx package supplies a /etc/init.d/nginx script that provides the usual start|stop|restart|reload ... functionality.

`/etc/init.d/nginx restart`

will restart nginx

as will

`service nginx restart`

Edit

[**Here**](http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/2/2/centos-adding-an-nginx-init-script) is a link to a script you can use as /etc/init.d/nginx.

Comment: Depends on your repository. The Nginx source does not provide init scripts so if you like being updated and compile from source you will have to get one from the wiki.

Comment: I must have more coffee before answering questions ...

Comment: what does service nginx restart point to and is it appropriate to reload something when a change is made to init.d/nginx ? My two commands (/etc/init.d/nginx and service nginx) seem out of sync.

Comment: @Danny: dunno I wrote this >2 years ago.

Answer (score 21):

http://wiki.nginx.org/CommandLine

inside the links there are some command for start and stop nginx server

for starting nginx:

```
/usr/bin/nginx
```

for stoping  nginx:

```
/usr/bin/nginx -s stop
```

`/usr/bin` depends on where you install your nginx

Answer (score 7):

For some reason, on the embedded system I am working on it is:

```
systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: This question and most of the answers are eight years old and obsolete. That is "some reason". This is the correct way to do it on current Linux operating systems.

Comment: Ok, so maybe it is not just true for embedded systems then

Answer (score 1):

After editing the configuration files, I restart it like this on OpenBSD:

```
kill -HUP `cat /var/run/nginx.pid` && date && sleep 1 && \
    tail -2 /var/www/logs/error.log ; date
```

The `HUP` signal makes it re-read its configuration files, the `tail` shows whether any errors have been encountered, the `date` puts those errors into the context (an error has occurred only if the time from `date` matches the time from the log), and `sleep 1` ensures that there are no race conditions between reading from the log prior to nginx having had a time to write to it.

This is how it looks:

```
Cns# kill -HUP `cat /var/run/nginx.pid` && date && sleep 1 && tail -2 /var/www/logs/error.log ; date
Tue Feb 12 10:58:52 PST 2013
2013/02/12 10:03:35 [emerg] 8120#0: directive "set" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/etc.ngx.grok/bxr.su.conf:226
2013/02/12 10:04:19 [emerg] 8120#0: invalid return code "$uri_def" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/etc.ngx.grok/bxr.su.conf:231
Tue Feb 12 10:58:53 PST 2013
Cns#
```

The fact that the time from the log is not between times printed by `date` indicates that no errors have been encountered this time around, and the new configuration is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

You can find init scripts in the NginX Wiki: http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#Init_Scripts

The restart function runs the following command:

```
BASEDIR=
$BASEDIR/sbin/nginx -s stop
$BASEDIR/sbin/nginx $BASEDIR/conf/nginx.conf
```

If you've nginx installed in /opt/nginx, replace `BASEDIR=` by `BASEDIR=/opt/nginx`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, packages installed from source don't install startup script at `/etc/init.d/`. You have two options.

1- You can look for a script in the source code directory or on the website, and customise it if needed.

2- You can copy a startup script for another package from your system and customise it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to check which path consists of your Nginx binary files. for that, you can run `which nginx`  which will give output like /usr/bin/nginx then you can simply restart you nginx server like `systemctl restart nginx` or  `servcie nginx restart`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/517473)

Comment: This was a useful response and answers the question just fine. `which nginx` helped me determine nginx was installed in sbin/ and required a sudo to operate.